# How to initialize a MPSMatrixMultiplication in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, metal

In Swift, we use

```
matrixMultiplication = MPSMatrixMultiplication(device: device, transposeLeft: false, transposeRight: false, resultRows: rowsC, resultColumns: columnsC, interiorColumns: columnsA, alpha: 1, beta: 0)
```

But when I try to call the method `initWithDevice` on `MPSMatrixMultiplication`, like [MPSMatrixMultiplication initWithDeivce ...]", it shows "No known class method for selector 'initWithDevice'"

So what's the correct way to declare a MPSMatrix in Objective-C? Isn't this method a class method since it returns a pointer to the object it initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't this method a class method

No, Objective-C initializers are instance methods. You have to create an instance with `alloc`. So

```
MPSMatrixMultiplication* mult = [[MPSMatrixMultiplication alloc] initWith...];
```

That (`alloc-init`) is always the pattern for initialization in Objective-C.